Planet where tourists are weighed on arrival and departure so it keeps its mass to prevent orbital destabilization
I'm looking for a story in which, as I remember, there is a planet (perhaps a moon?) with a critical mass that has to be mantained, so the planet doesn't fall in an unstable orbit. Thus, all visitors (mainly tourists) are carefully weighed with their baggage upon arrival and departure, and the differences in mass - if there is any - must be compensated, by force if necessary.
I don't remember anything else about the story.
Additional data: I probably read it before 2000, possibly in the 80's. Written in English, possibly translated into Spanish.
It might be just a story somebody tells in a larger book.

Incidentally, changing the mass of an orbiting body doesn’t change its orbit. Of course, how you change the mass might because that’s how rockets work.

@DaleM only approximately true if its mass is insignificant compared to the body it is orbiting.  You can definitely change an orbit, and even make it completely unbound, by removing mass. Consider what might happen to the Moon if you removed 99% of Earth's mass, say. Or vice-versa. There's no such thing as one body orbiting another, by the way, they always mutually orbit each other.

@Kyle in the context of a habitable planet orbiting a star, the mass of the plane t is insignificant.

This is a throwaway joke in the eighth chapter of Douglas Adams' The HitchHiker's Guide to the Galaxy (1979). English is the original language. There is a Spanish Translation, "Guía del autoestopista galáctico".
HHGttG remains famous to this day for its many slightly absurdist jokes, and one of them concerns

(...) the fact that the fabulously beautiful planet Bethselamin is now so
worried about the cumulative erosion by ten billion visiting tourists
a year that any net imbalance between the amount you eat and the
amount you excrete whilst on the planet is surgically removed from
your bodyweight when you leave: so every time you go to the lavatory
there it is vitally important to get a receipt.)

Which sounds close enough to be a possible answer.

Note, the passage is almost the same in the original radio episode from 1978, except that there are ten million tourists a year which doesn't sound like very much for an entire planet.

@DanielRoseman IIRC there is also an animation in the TV adaption illustrating the corrective surgery. Alas I did not find it on youtube.

@DanielRoseman It's still ten million more tourists than visited Earth this year (to the best of my knowledge )

@TripeHound, no, that's n...  why yes, yes, exactly.

The most absurd part is requiring a lavatory receipt, if they were that concerned they'd just record your weight when you arrived and compare it on departure.

@MarkRansom That's not a way to compare the weight of food eaten and material excreted. Your body weight is much more affected by the amount of carbon and oxygen you inhale and exhale than it is by how much you eat and excrete.

@ToddWilcox why would those things matter less than food and waste?

@MarkRansom You’d have to ask the Bethselamins. They’re the ones who decided mass eaten and excreted is what they wanted to control, not body weight.

@MarkRansom Mass, not weight: otherwise, aliens such as Mass Effect's "Gasbags" and "Hanar" (who float, and thus have zero weight) would find themselves with a peculiar loophole.  Similarly, weighted clothing would probably become popular for arrivals, and packed away for departures.  And, of course, receipts for both intake and outtake allow 'corrections' to be applied on a per-locale basis: so mass won't "migrate" from popular tourist attractions to the spaceports…  (Also: Adams was, like Pratchett, often of the opinion 'why let a silly thing like "logic" get in the way of a good joke?')

@MarkRansom they are worried about erosion, not mass, so they obviously want to use the waste as landfill. Else this would just be a satirical novel making fun at silly regulations, and we all know that would be impossible ;-)

Given Douglas Adams wry sense of humour and the many jokes, epithets etc that he put in his books all poking fun at our society (us who still think digital watches are a good idea...) and the control some countries exert about what people try to cross borders with (Australia customs, New Zealand customs ) then he seemed to make a valid point.

@SolarMike, 'scuse me? Some of us never thought that digital watches were a good idea. (Well, OK, We may have thought it was cool when James Bond wore a Hamilton Pulsar in "Live and Let Die.")

10 billion (1e10) people a year might sound like a lot, but even a very small body like Ceres is 1e21 kg. If every person took away 10 kg that's 1e11 kg per year. It would take 100 million years to remove 1% of the mass. So this is Bethselamin security-theater/green-washing. Then again, this is a book series that does span the entire age of the Universe.

@SolomonSlow 'scuse me? it was an example of the way DA looks at things and pokes fun at things, much like the talking cow in the restaurant saying about the vegetables having opinion about being eaten... Not saying you or anyone else needs / likes a digital watch.

@Schwern but given that fact would that stop politicians making a stupid regulation? Given some of the stuff they push through?
